# c - How to typedef an already typedefed identifier?

Tags: c

There is a header file `stack.h`:

```
typedef char ElemType;

typedef struct{
    ElemType data[MaxSize];
    int top;
} SqStack;

int Push_Sq(SqStack *s, ElemType e);

int Pop_Sq(SqStack *s, ElemType *e);

int GetTop_Sq(SqStack *s, ElemType *e);
```

And now I have some source file including this header, I want to use `int` for `ElemType` instead of `char`, is it possible? What should I do?(I don't want to modify the original header file)

Comment: Change the first typedef...

Comment: Though of an answer starting with `#define char int`, but no, it's too evil.

Comment: @Anton, that was my first thought as well but it's likely to break all sorts of things down the track :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you're compiling the code, there's nothing stopping you from editing the source file itself, or using a different source file (a slightly modified copy of the one you've shown), to change the underlying type to an `int`. In other words, changing the first line to:

```
typedef int ElemType;
```

You'll need to be careful as that may break assumptions made elsewhere, but that would be the first thing I'd try.

If, as stated in the edit, you don't want to modify the original header file, you can just include it thus:

```
#define char int
#include "stack.h"
#undef char
```

This may work as `char` is only used in that header file in the `typedef` itself so the effects are localised.

Keep in mind that all translation units in the current build should use that trick otherwise you may end up with some very unusual bugs.

---

In my opinion, you'd be better off forking the entire stack implementation to try and keep things clean, or make the stack able to handle any data type (a little more complex, but doable).

Comment: But IIRC `define`'ing reserved words is technically undefined, even if it works for most implementation.

Comment: I tried `define char int` method but at compiling the compiler generated a lot of error information, which I don't understand.

Comment: @CDT, then I would strongly suggest forking the code to give you an `int` version. That's probably going to be the least amount of trouble.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks, I think I'd better try templates of cpp instead of c. Your suggestion is applicable but seems a little tricky.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to do unfortunately. You can refactor the code to make the type a `#define`, so something like this in the header file:

```
#ifndef ELEMTYPE
# define ELEMTYPE char
#endif

typedef ELEMTYPE ElemType;
```

Then in the source file *before* you include the header file you can do

```
#define ELEMTYPE int
```

This can however be **dangerous** if used from multiple files and you don't have the same `ELEMTYPE` in *all* source files.

Comment: I like the idea of refactoring, +1.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a little tricky. Two "elemtype"s is a little bit confusing, I think I should try cpp instead.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

In C++ an alternative is to declare those identifiers in different *namespaces*.

In C you can #define them and later #undef them when necessary to make a new #define.

Comment: In C++ the solution would rather be templates I would think.

Comment: Thanks, I should try cpp instead.

Comment: @CDT, C++ is a _very_ different language, with it's own steep learning curve.